# Creating a ASP.Net MVC route with just forward slashes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a action in a controller that looks like this

```
public ActionResult Transactions(string type) {}
```

To access this controller and pass in a type property value I have to type

> www.mysite/controller/transactions?type=sometype

but what I want is to pass something like this

> www.mysite.com/controller/transactions/sometype

So I create a route config param in the RouteConfig.cs file like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "TransactionRoute",
   url: "user/transactions/{type}",
   defaults: new { controller = "user", action = "transactions", type = "made" },
   constraints: new { title = @"^[A-Za-z]+$" }
);
```

but now if I pass a url like this

> www.mysite.com/controller/transactions/made

the value of the string type in the action is null

Am I allowed to do this or did I do something wrong?

Here is my routeconfig.cs file

```js
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TransactionRoute",
    url: "user/transactions/{type}",
    defaults: new {
      controller = "user", action = "transactions", type = "made"
    },
    constraints: new {
      title = @ "^[A-Za-z]+$"
    }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RateRoute",
    url: "rate/event/{id}",
    defaults: new {
      controller = "rate", action = "event"
    },
    constraints: new {
      id = @ "\d+"
    }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ReviewRoute",
    url: "rate/review/{id}",
    defaults: new {
      controller = "rate", action = "review"
    },
    constraints: new {
      id = @ "\d+"
    }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SpaceCleanRoute",
    url: "space/{id}",
    defaults: new {
      controller = "space", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    constraints: new {
      id = @ "\d+"
    }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SpacePendingRoute",
    url: "space/{id}/{pending}",
    defaults: new {
      controller = "space", action = "index", pending = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    constraints: new {
      id = @ "\d+"
    }
  );


  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PublicSpaceRoute",
    url: "space/public/{title}",
    defaults: new {
      controller = "space", action = "public"
    },
    constraints: new {
      title = @ "^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$"
    }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {
      controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
  );


}
```

Comment: Your code code is correct. If its not working, its most likely because you routes are in the wrong order

Comment: Show `RouteConfig.cs`

Comment: I'll post routeconfig.cs what order does it need to be in?

Comment: `www.mysite.com/user/transactions/sometype` should match for the `TransactionRoute`. Also I see no need for the `title` constraint.

Comment: yes, well, then why does sometype in the action keep showing a null value?

Comment: oh I removed the constraint and it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`www.mysite.com/user/transactions/sometype` should match for the `TransactionRoute`.

Also I see no need for the `title` constraint based on the route template.

Remove the `title` constraint

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "TransactionRoute",
   url: "user/transactions/{type}",
   defaults: new { controller = "user", action = "transactions", type = "made" }   
);
```